# Delete all list items which are checked

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) binding to a database with a Custom [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).
in each of my list items I have 4 texts, image and checkbox (each one is set to focusable:false).

In the list itself I have a long button so when I press on it, I want it to delete all the
rows which thire checkboxes are 'checked'.

Now, I have tried many techniques in order to achieve a simple operation (click listeners, CheckedtextView as shown in the tutorial) but was not successful.

There is also another weird phenomenon occurring, after I @Override [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29), also i dont get any calls at all while I am pressing on any of the list's rows.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve these issues? Thanks.

Thanks,

Moshic.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Can you show exactly what you are trying, and what the expected behavior is?

Comment: okie.. so i try again, ive got database(sqllite) and i wanna show it on list activity. now that database is binded bia SimpleCursorAdapter to my list. now each of my list item has 3 textViews and one checkbox item. now everything is fine, i can see those textviews after ive binded them to my database, the prob i`am having is the multichoise of my checkboxes. i cant handle them correcly, my expected behavior is: delete the list item's which thire checkboxes are 'checked (check=true). as i wrote above i tried some technics, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `super.onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long);`? if so, try write out a `Log.d("ListView", "My list has been clicked");` and see if that comes out in the Logcat. If it doesn't, try `extends ListActivity` in your activity declaration. comment back if you want my help, I'll be ready to help as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

1. create your own adapter with following features

   -in getView() you have to set click listener for check box(it will be own listener for each check box)

   -each element of adapter contains flag checked/unchecked, and you should set it by check box click listener from previous point
2. in activity with delete button click listener you have to get checked elements from adapter and do with them what you want
3. after then you should update list view for example by calling (your adapter).notifyDataSetChanged()